# php constructor variable not getting accessed in the functions below

Tags: php, class, constructor, class-constructors

I have initialized a new instance of a library in the __construct(){} method of a PHP class and equated it to a variable,

but now I want to use this variable to access methods of the library inside another function but PHP is not allowing me do that.

```
class Demo 
{

public function __construct()
    {

    parent::__construct(new PaymentModel);

    $this->api = new Api(config("razorpay", "key_id"), config("razorpay", "key_secret"));

    }

public function createOrder()
  {
    $order = $api->order->create();
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($order); die;

  }
}
```

I looked at the __construct documentation and some other answers here on stack overflow but all they did was confuse me more than helping me out.

Please help me figure this out as I am a starter myself in tech.

Comment: Add $this to api in your createOrder method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined `api` as a class variable ([property](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)). Use `$this->api` to acces this class variable (property) in other methods of your class.

```
// This class probably inherits some base class
class Demo extends BaseDemo 
{

public function __construct()
    {

    parent::__construct(new PaymentModel);

    $this->api = new Api(config("razorpay", "key_id"), config("razorpay", "key_secret"));

    }

public function createOrder()
  {
    $order = $this->api->order->create();
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($order); die;

  }
}
```

Also check your class definition - if `parent::__construct()` is called, then your class probably [inherits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) some base class. If this is not the case, remove `parent::__construct()` call.

Comment: Yes, it does inherit a base class. I just removed all the non-useful information from the question so that I can target only the problem at hand. Your answer was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use $this->api in your class, you will need to set it as an attribute.

so :

```
class Demo 
{
private $api;

public function __construct()
    {

    parent::__construct(new PaymentModel);

    $this->api = new Api(config("razorpay", "key_id"), config("razorpay", "key_secret"));

    }

public function createOrder()
  {
    $order = $this->api->order->create();
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($order); die;

  }
}
```

Also, as notified by other, you are to construct a parent class while your class 'Demo' does not extend any other class.

Answer (score 0):

To access object variables you need to use $this. In your case change the first line in createOrder() to `$order = $this->api->order->create();`

Also you appear to be trying to run the classes parents constructor in your constructor. But the class doesn't have a parent.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling parent::__construct(new PaymentModel); on a class which doeasn't extend any base class.

Answer (score 0):

declare variable $api in a class then only accessible to other function body